# Lower bound formulas of smallest eigenvalues of Hankel matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, hankel-matrices

Are there simple and reliable formulas (using matrix elements and matrix trace) of lower bound for the smallest eigenvalue of a matrix of the following type?
It's Hankel matrix
[image]

Comment: Probably not relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209387/bounds-on-the-smallest-eigenvalue-of-a-hankel-matrix

Comment: @KeithMcClary I have not seen this question and it is not my authorship. That formula uses a determinant. Are there simpler formulas without determinant?

Comment: I don't know. Could you clarify your Question - do you want the exact smallest eigenvalue?

Comment: @KeithMcClary As simple as possible formulas for the lower bound of the smallest eigenvalue. This is now reflected in the topic name and in the question itself.

Comment: It is still not clear to me whether you want an exact formula for the smallest eigenvalue, or just some number ("lower bound") smaller than the smallest eigenvalue.

Comment: Lower bound formula for the smallest eigenvalue. Something like that: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379580902013 These formulas are simple but give incorrect estimates. It often happens that when calculating the minimum eigenvalue is much less than the lower bound predicted by these formulas.